# Avoid an unintentional data type conversion when using inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am joining two tables into a third with different inner joins columns. When I run the query, the value for `invMarketgroups.marketGroupName` is mentioned in the error as

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Blueprints & Reactions' to data type int.

The destination column is named the same as the starting column and is using `varchar(100)` as the data type.

```
INSERT INTO Aivowetware
SELECT
    invTypes.typeID
    , invTypes.typeName
    , invTypes.marketGroupID
    , industryActivitymaterials.typeID
    , industryActivitymaterials.activityID
    , industryActivityMaterials.materialTypeID
    , industryActivitymaterials.quantity
    , invMarketGroups.marketGroupName
FROM 
    invTypes
INNER JOIN 
    industryActivityMaterials ON industryActivitymaterials.typeID = invTypes.typeID
INNER JOIN 
    invMarketGroups ON invMarketGroups.marketGroupID = invTypes.marketGroupID
```

I have checked the column names and data types and they are identical. I want the inner join to complete without receiving an error with a data type conversion I am not attempting.

Comment: 1. Always specify the columns that you are inserting into - it avoids all sorts of issues and is clearer to understand. 2. The mostly likely cause I can see is that you are attempting to insert `marketGroupName ` into an int column, but as I can't see your table definition I can't be sure.

Comment: I also highly recommend table aliases, they will make your query *much* easier to follow.

Comment: Note, its nothing to do with the joins

Comment: I suspect you're assuming the selected columns will be inserted into columns with the same name? Thats not how it works. 
Just specify the columns that each value should be inserted into.

Answer (score 4):

If you're absolutely sure you have the column types setup correctly, then the most likely answer is that the selected columns are not being inserted into the columns you expect them to. You should be specifying them in your insert statement. Assuming they have the same names:

```
INSERT INTO Aivowetware
(typeID, typeName, marketGroupID, typeID, activityID, materialTypeID 
    , quantity, marketGroupName)
SELECT
    IT.typeID
    , IT.typeName
    , IT.marketGroupID
    , IAM.typeID
    , IAM.activityID
    , IAM.materialTypeID
    , IAM.quantity
    , IMG.marketGroupName
FROM invTypes IT
INNER JOIN industryActivityMaterials IAM
    ON IAM.typeID = IT.typeID
INNER JOIN invMarketGroups IMG
    ON IMG.marketGroupID = IT.marketGroupID
```